# importing apps into urls.py

Tags: python, django-views, directory, importerror

I am trying to import views from my apps into the urls.py file. For awhile, I was able to using "from app_name.views import view_name", but for some reason now it is not recognizing the app name.

I did not change anything in my settings.py file so I'm not sure what caused this. I did delete some migrations and an my database.

One thing that is weird is that I can import them if I go up a folder so, "from src.appname.views" and this seems to work, but is not what I want since by base directory is the src folder.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import home_page, history, more_information, prop_analysis
from Product.views import property_analysis_tools, property_analysis_results

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_page),
    path('home', home_page),
    path('history', history),
    path('information', more_information),
    path('analyze', prop_analysis),
    path('results', property_analysis_results)
```

Another odd thing is that when I run the server, all of these views seem to work. Can Django sometimes give off false errors?

Comment: Please, can you update your question with the content of `urls.py`?

Comment: in this file, both 'pages' and 'Product' have a red underline and have an error saying unresolved reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Django in order to import an app.view into project urls, we create an additional urls.py in every app and link that urls.py into
our project urls.py , just as shown below

change **project urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls', namespace="pages")),
    ]
```

create another **urls.py** in your **pages** app
as below, similarly in any other apps.

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (home_page,history,....)

app_name = 'pages'

urlpatterns = [
   
    path(' ', homepage , name='homepage-view'),
    path('history/',history, name='history-view'),


  ]
```

Every other view from respective app.views will be included in corresponding app.urls [if u have multiple apps]

nB: changes may occur according to your settings.py configurations,

for more, read this [django URL documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/)

watch [Corey Schafer playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p) best Django tutorial for beginners

Comment: The views.py file is in my app which is in the same folder as my project. So I have a folder src that contains the project and app.